# General Topology, showing if the intersection is non empty then x is in the closure of A

Tags: general-topology

Show that $\forall \epsilon N(x,\epsilon) \cap A \neq \emptyset$, then $x$ is in the closure of $A$.

Definition:
$A'$ is the set of all accumulation or limit points.
$\overline{A} = A \cup A'$ - this is known as the closure of $A$.
A point $p\in \mathbb{R}$ is an accumulation point if and only if every open set $G$ containing $p$ contains a point of $A$ different from $p$.

Proof: For every $\epsilon$, we have an open set $N(x,\epsilon)\subset A\in \mathbb{R}$. This implied $x\in A$, we want to show that $x\in\overline{A}$.

I am having a hard time with this one, it has to do with the properties of closure. If anyone can help me I would greatly appreciate it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In other words, you want to show that every open set $G$ containing $x$ contains a point of $A$. Since $G$ is open, you can always find a $N(x,\epsilon)\subset G$ for some $\epsilon$ and your assumption tells us that $N(x,\epsilon)\cap A\not=\emptyset$ and hence $G\cap A\not=\emptyset$.

Comment: So since $G\cap A = \emptyset$ then $x\in\overline{A}$?